# How to get speech regnition on android things app?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, android-things

**Hi, I'm using:**

- The [Google Voice Kit](https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice/) for the hardware
- This [controler for the Voice Hat](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/voicehat) (Recognizes perfectly  the button and the button LED)
- This [app code](https://github.com/sergy09/Maggie) GitHub Repository

When I start speech recognizerintent it doesn't work and spend me this error:

> 2018-12-12 14:35:14.064 6546-6546/tck.com.maggie E/SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service

**¿How can i make it work?**

**Notes:** This work perfectly on smartphone, I don´t know if i need implement other driver for de mic and the speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it installing via adb tool [Google Assistant APK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googleassistant) in my android things

1. Get apk with some [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apk-downloader/fgljidimohbcmjdabiecfeikkmpbjegm) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/direct-apk-downloader-2018/) extension
2. Connect via [adb tool](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi) to your android things
3. `adb install /path-of-your-apk/app.apk`

After that, SpeechRecognizer work fine

Answer (score 1):

That means either the user doesn't have a speech recognizer installed at all, or doesn't have one configured to run. There's nothing you can do to fix that, the user has to install one.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code is looking for a native `SpeechRecognizer` service, but is unable to detect one. This is an optional service that is implemented on most Android mobile devices, but we did not include it on the Android Things system images.

You can, however, implement this functionality using an external speech recognition service such as the [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/). Here is a link to the [Android code sample](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/samples#android_sample) for Cloud Speech.